# Selection from a pandas DataFrame based on auxiliary series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a Series:

```
ser = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
df = pd.DataFrame([['c',1],['d',2],['a',3]], columns=['first', 'second'])
```

and want to get the DataFrame:

```
   first  second
0  c      1
1  a      3
```

That is, I want to say something like `df[df.first in ser.tolist()]`, but taking into account that `df.first` is a `Series` and not an element thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1***
`query`

```
df.query('first in @ser')
```

***option 2***
`isin`

```
df[df['first'].isin(ser)]
```

Both yield

```
  first  second
0     c       1
2     a       3
```

---

***timing reference***

```
def query():
    return df.query('first in @ser')

def isin():
    return df[df['first'].isin(ser)]


results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 1000, 100000], name='group size'),
    columns=pd.Index(['query', 'isin'], name='method'),
)

from timeit import timeit

for i in results.index:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(first=np.random.randint(10, size=i)))
    s = pd.Series(range(5))
    for j in results.columns:
        results.set_value(
            i, j,
            timeit(
                '{}()'.format(j),
                'from __main__ import {}, df, s'.format(j),
                number=100
            )
        )

results.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just to mention for future users that option 2 is significantly faster than option 1: 438 µs versus 1.34 ms.

Comment: @splinter don't forget to accept the answer and upvote as you see appropriate.

Comment: @piSquared, no worries I don't forget. Nice plot too :)